# Properties of $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ in base $mt+r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $m$ is any fix positive integer and integer $0\le r< m$ and $t$ is a variable $(t=0,1,2,3,...)$. In below, $[a]$ shows greatest integer function of $a$.

We can express $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ as a polynomial in terms of $mt+r$ as $$\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(x_it+y_i)(mt+r)^i$$ for some integer $0\le x_i,y_i<m.$

My observations,

1. $x_i\equiv r^{m-1-i}\pmod{m}$ for $i=0,1,...,m-1$
2. If $r>0$ then $y_i\le r-1$ for $i=0,1,...,m-1$

How to prove above observation?

---

Edit:

3. observation: $y_i=\left[\frac{x_ir}{m}\right]$

Partial Solution to second observation: because we can express $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ as $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(x_it+y_i)(mt+r)^i$ here $x_it+y_i$ shows digits in base $mt+r$ for all $t\ge N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ . Implies $x_i+y_i\le m+r-1$ and from first observation and third observation and $x_i< m$ implies $y_i\le r-1$

---

Following observations which have proved and simple as well

If $m$ is prime then $x_{m-1}$ and $x_0$ is 1 for all $r$, $0<r<m$

If $r=0$, then $x_{m-1}$ is 1 and all other $x_i,y_i$ are 0.

If $r=1$, then $x_i$ is 1 and $y_i$ is 0 for all $i$

Example, let m= 5

r: $\left[\frac{(5t+r)^5}{5}\right]= ([x_4, x_3, x_2, x_1, x_0] t+[y_4, y_3, y_2, y_1, y_0])[(5t+r)^4,(5t+r)^3,(5t+r)^2,5t+r,1]^T$

r=0: $\left[\frac{(5t)^5}{5}\right]= ([1, 0, 0, 0, 0] t+[0, 0, 0, 0, 0])[(5t)^4,(5t)^3,(5t)^2,5t,1]^T$

r=1: $\left[\frac{(5t+1)^5}{5}\right]= ( [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] t+[0, 0, 0, 0, 0])[(5t+1)^4,(5t+1)^3,(5t+1)^2,5t+1,1]^T$

r=2: $\left[\frac{(5t+2)^5}{5}\right]= ([1, 2, 4, 3, 1] t+[0, 0, 1, 1, 0])[(5t+2)^4,(5t+2)^3,(5t+2)^2,5t+2,1]^T$

r=3: $\left[\frac{(5t+3)^5}{5}\right]= ([1, 3, 4, 2, 1] t+[0, 1, 2, 1, 0])
[(5t+3)^4,(5t+3)^3,(5t+3)^2,5t+3,1]^T$

r=4: $\left[\frac{(5t+4)^5}{5}\right]= ( [1, 4, 1, 4, 1] t+[0, 3, 0, 3, 0])
[(5t+4)^4,(5t+4)^3,(5t+4)^2,5t+4,1]^T$

Python code

```
for i in range(100):
    m = int(input('put value for m= '))
    
    def digits(x,y):
        if x == 1:
            return 1
        if x == 0:
            return 0
        res=[]
        while y:
            res.append(y%x)
            y//=x
        return res[::-1]
    
    #for coverting in base by index-wise
    def d(a,x,b,y):
        re = []
        for i in range(len(digits(b,y))):
            re.append(digits(b,y)[i]-digits(a,x)[i])
        return re
    
    l=[]
    
    s=lambda n: (n)**m//m
    
    for k in range(0,500):
        l.append(s(k))
    
       
    l5 = []
    for i in range(0,m):
        if d(l.index(l[i::m][-2]),l[i::m][-2],l.index(l[i::m][-1]),l[i::m][-1])==d(l.index(l[i::m][-3]),l[i::m][-3],l.index(l[i::m][-2]),l[i::m][-2]):
            print('r={0}: '.format(i),d(l.index(l[i::m][-2]),l[i::m][-2],l.index(l[i::m][-1]),l[i::m][-1]),'t+',end="")
            p1 = d(l.index(l[i::m][-2]),l[i::m][-2],l.index(l[i::m][-1]),l[i::m][-1])
            r1 = digits(l.index(l[i::m][-1]),l[i::m][-1])
            w01 = r2 = d(l.index(l[i::m][-2]),l[i::m][-2],l.index(l[i::m][-1]),l[i::m][-1])
            w02 = r3 = []
            for k in range(0,len(r2)):
                r3.append(r1[k]-((l.index(l[i::m][-1]))//m)*r2[k])
            l5.append([p1[-1],r3[-1]])    
            print(r3,'\n')
            if i == m-1:
                print('table complete')
        else:
            print('diffrence is not linear and table incomplete\n ')
            break
```

Here, [MO link for related problems](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362137/149083), (*proof for such types of expression*)

Comment: What does greatest integer function mean?  Do you mean floor function?

Comment: What is motivation / application?

Comment: Have you tried expanding your [x/n] as (x -x mod n)/n?   Where x mod n is x’s least nonneg residue module n?

Comment: @DanielDonnelly Yes it is floor function. Motivation: maybe we can understand structure or pattern of digits for perticular expression. Actually I didn't tried much. I'm just excited with second observation so I post it. I will go with your 3rd comment please expand it for better understand. Thanks.

Comment: This formula appears on the Wikipedia page for floor / ceiling.  I always try it out but it rarely works for completely solving a given problem.  It's just a first step anyway.    Anyhow the point is you've dropped the troublesome floor in favor of a possibly less troublesome modular residue.  And you combine terms etc, because the floor isn't blocking you any more.

Comment: Interesting observation, and looking forward to more 

Comment: @DanielDonnelly Here is related Question on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/q/463137/149083

Comment: Can you explain how “$\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ as a polynomial in terms of $mt+r$ as $$\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(x_it+y_i)(mt+r)^i$$ for some integer $0\le x_i,y_i<m.$”